# Peekaboo Bug in IE 11 (AdSense not showing until window is interacted with)

Tags: css, internet-explorer, adsense, internet-explorer-11, haslayout

I am completely puzzled and discouraged. There is the following problem on a website: Google AdSense banners are **not showing** up in Internet Explorer **until the browser is somehow interacted with**.

I have checked it on four completely different computers and the problem looks the same: the ads are not showing at all, until you do one of the following:

- resize the window, or
- press "alt" button on the keyboard, or
- open up the console (F12)

In other words, the ads show up right in their right place after I somehow interact with the browser window. And that is happening in Internet Explorer 11! On four totally different computers.

I can't wrap my mind about it. Does anybody have any kind of idea what this might be?

Comment: Have you validated that the HTML is valid?  The page shows 51 errors.  I'd start there.  Weird behavior is usually associated with invalid markup.  Also, why the IE8 compatibility tag?

Comment: I agree that the code of the webpage is a total mess. I still think the the problem is not connected to it. There is obviously some kind of IE compatibility-peculiarity going on.

Comment: You have unclosed tags, forcing compatibility to IE8 mode, and all kinds of other problems.  These are the #1 reason for strange behavior in browsers.  You ask our advice, and then refuse to accept it.. well, good luck.

Comment: I'm not refusing... :) Thanks for advice.
I will be trying to fix some of that and see what happens... It's not my website, though, I'm not going to completely rewrite it.

I just found this problem really strange. It's one thing not showing an element at all, and another showing it after subtle interaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally found the solution. It was indeed a "ie-compatibility" issue, yet not obvious and not that easy to find.

Probably some wordpress plugin added the following line to the header:

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7"/>`

I changed it to

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"/>`

And it worked. Why do I say it was not easy to find? Well, I played a lot with compatibility settings in the IE browser and nothing worked. And again the way the bug represented itself would never make me think that such line was responsible.